# How to change the theme for LMS ans CMS in open edX?

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, bitnami, openedx

I am New to Open edX installed openedx version edx-ginko.2-1 using bitnami .I tried to install and customise theme for open edX platform. But it is not showing me any changes.

I followed the instructions from bitnami documentation

```
sudo installdir/apps/edx/bin/paver.edxapp update_assets lms --settings=aws
```

**Folder Structure:**

```
 -installdir/apps/edx/var/themes/
   |-my-custom-theme
     |-cms
       |-static
       |-templates
     |-lms
       |-static
       |-templates

**lms.env.json and cms.env.json:**

 "COMPREHENSIVE_THEME_DIRS": [
     "installdir/apps/edx/var/themes/"
 ],
 "ENABLE_COMPREHENSIVE_THEMING": true,
 "FEATURES": {
     ...
     "USE_CUSTOM_THEME": true
 },
 "THEME_NAME": "my-custom-theme"
```

But it is not giving me any error on update_assets for lms

i also tried with edx documentation for changing the theme which is also not working for me.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

thanks in advance

new update i was able to compile the theme but still it is not showing up

Comment: for those who think this question is unclear or doesnot show any research effort please can you tell me why do you think so . so i can improve my question

Answer (score 0):

Are you restarting the services after recompile? You can do it running

```
sudo installdir/ctlscript.sh restart
```

Comment: i restarted the several times but i couldn't feel any change can you help me why

Comment: i was not able set any other theme what am i doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're following [this documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/edx/#how-to-enable-and-apply-a-custom-theme), when it says commands including the word *installdir*, you should replace this word with the real path where you installed your application. Can this be the problem?

The default installation path will be a sub-directory of your home directory if you are running the installer as a regular user, or `/opt/APPNAME-VERSION` if you are running the installer as the root user.

Can you repeat the process replacing `installdir` with the real path?

Comment: hey i am using absolute path for theme

Comment: i think like it might be the issue with latest release of open edx . the theme which i have been using is not supporting in it

Comment: my saas files are getting compiled and creating css

Answer (score 0):

Also,do change in **lms.env.json** and **cms.env.json** file:

`"DEFAULT_SITE_THEME": "your_custom_theme_name"`

Then restart the services by running this command:

`sudo installdir/ctlscript.sh restart`